# Create a signal for each item in QListWidget

Tags: pyqt, qlistwidget

I want to create a list of items using QListWidget and set it up so each time I click (select) an item a different method is executed. The way I thought about going about solving this is by connecting the list to a method that will check for the index and depending on the item index it will generate a signal connected to a different method. Thing is, I don't know how to generate this signal if I don't have a button or anything. The method is just checking for item index.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need the signal? Why not just call the method directly?

Comment: You already have a bunch of signals for when you select, click or double click on an item: `itemSelectionChanged`, `itemActivated`, `itemClicked`... See the [Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate? @ ekhumoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward idea would be to connect the `itemClicked` signal to a slot in which a method is called depending on the clicked index. In this case you don't need a signal for every item.

But if you really want to create a "clicked" signal for each item and connect it to its respective slot(s), you could do it like this:

1. Subclass the `QListWidgetItem` and add a `clicked` signal to it. [How to add custom signals](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Adding%20custom%20signals%20to%20a%20simple%20painted%20widget)
2. While filling the QListWidget, connect each item with its slots depending on its index.
3. Connect the `itemClicked` signal of the QListWidget to a slot, that emits the clicked item's signal like this:

   ```
   def itemClickedSlot(item):  
       item.clicked.emit()
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I will try doing this. ekhumoro says that I can call the method directly. Do you know what he is referring to?

Comment: As far as I understand his comment I'd say it is the first alternative that I explained to you: instead of having a signal for each item, just calling the method directly depending on the clicked index.

Comment: Thank you, x squared. I tried to make your answer work but I didn't know how to add a click signal to each list item (it says that QListWidgetItem does not posses this attribute). After many attempts, what I ended up doing is using the currentRowChanged signal of the QListWidget class and connecting it to a method that calls a specific function based on index. It is very similar to what you mentioned. So certainly, you put me in the right track. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you made a mistake in step 1. Did you subclass QListWidgetItem, then defined a signal `clicked` in it and then later added instances of the subclass instead of the base class to your QListWidget? See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Adding%20custom%20signals%20to%20a%20simple%20painted%20widget) to learn how to add a custom signal to your subclass.

Comment: @theCHemist90. As x squared surmised, what I meant is that you should make **one** connection to the list-widget's `itemClicked` signal, which will then send the item that was clicked. You can then do `listwidget.row(item)` to get the index and call the appropriate method.

Comment: @xsquared. Thanks. Yes,what I meant by "I couldn't make it work" was I did not know how to do it.

Comment: @ekhumoro. Thank you!